# How to effectively use an existing project in my code?

Tags: c

Let's say I want to use `mnemonic_generate` function from https://github.com/trezor/trezor-crypto/blob/master/bip39.c in my code (actually I want to use many others from the repository but let's just consider this). I have cloned the repo on my system. I can do make and it works. But I have a separate `.c` file in which I have `#include"relative/path/to/bip39.c"` And I try to call mnemonic_generate but it throws a lot of errors of the type `undefined reference to 'X'` (for example `undefined reference to random_buffer` and so on). I understand that this file in turn is trying to include other files which might contain the definitions of these undefined things but they are not getting included for some reason. Why is this happening and how to fix this?

The main reason I was confused was because I didn't know (Well I had studied but wasn't conscious of) the difference between compiling and linking. I also didn't know what a Makefile is and why do we need one. 
[This is how I ended up solving it](https://www.howtogeek.com/427086/how-to-use-linuxs-ar-command-to-create-static-libraries/)

Comment: Why is this tagged `c++` if you are writing in C?

Comment: The repository has a warning on top saying "Don't use this". You should probably follow that advice.

Comment: @uneven_mark I would use the repository linked in the warning. As much as I can see, the code in both looks same at this point. Also, I tagged `c++` because from what I understand it doesn't matter in this context and the answer would be relevant for both.

Comment: No the answer is different for C++, because the code in question is not designed to be used as a C++ library. There would be extra steps needed to be taken to use it with C++ code. I removed the tag, assuming that you are not actually compiling as C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just #include a single `.c` file from a complex project like this and expect it to work.  Life is not that simple.

Instead, the `readme.md` file for this project indicates that it is a library, so you need to link against that library (which you say you've already built) and #include the relevant **.h** files in your application wherever you want to call functions in the library.

Comment: The readme does not have concrete instructions and looking at the Makefile, it doesn't actually produce a static or shared library. It only compiles each `.c` to object files and links the tests/tools to all of them. I think the expectation is that one adds the required `.c` manually to ones project Makefile.

Comment: Really?  That's a poor show.  I would, in that case, figure out how to build it as a library and go from there.

Comment: Yes, but it explains OP's confusion. Also the repo has a warning at the top, not to use it...

Comment: So, to remove the `undefined reference to random_buffer` error, I must go to all of the headers included in `bip39.c` and see where it is defined, and then include that header in my code. Wouldn't that cascade very much? And since `bip39.c` does include them in its own file, shouldn't that be automatically be done by compiler?

Comment: There's a (big!) difference between `.c` files and `.h` files.  `.h` files don't contain any code - just the definitions the compiler needs to call that code.  The `c` files containing the code itself must either be compiled into your program _as separate translation units_ (**not** by #including them in other `.c` files), or, better, by compiling them into a separate library and then linking against it.  To build a library (which has a `.a` extension) from compiled `.c` files (which have a `.o` extension), use the `ar` utility.  Then link your program against the resulting `.a` file.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how to do either of these and would need to look it up. If you can refer me to a good source from where I can get started, that'd be great!

Comment: `man ar` would be a good starting point.  Hopefully,someone here knows how to integrate it into the existing Makefile (I don't use `make`, sorry).